# How to avoid too many For-Loops in Java?

Tags: java, idioms

I have a method which contains four **for-loops** and as you can see each loop does the same thing which seems to be a code smell. 
So Is there any better way to make it shorter and better?

Here is my code:

```
  void explodeDirections() {
    for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++)  
      if (!explode(x+i, y))
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++) 
      if (!explode(x, y+i))
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++) 
      if (!explode(x-i, y))
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++) 
      if (!explode(x, y-i))
        break;
  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

---

**Edit:**

Finally, I could find the way I wanted.

This is how I solved the issue:

```
 void explodeDirections(int x, int y) {
   for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++)  
     if (!explode(this.x + (i*x), this.y + (i*x)))
       break;
 }
```

And then you should call the method four times:

```
explodeDirections(1, 0);
explodeDirections(-1, 0);
explodeDirections(0, 1);
explodeDirections(0, -1);
```

Comment: With no other context, why not put your checks in one for block?

Comment: @possum can be done, but they might break at different values of `i` so some sort of additional logic is needed.

Comment: use OR condition to make it shorter

Comment: Since you aren't saving the values of `i` that break in each case, I assume the `explode` calls may have side-effects that require they be called in the order shown?

Comment: @lurker I'd guess this is for an "explosion" on a tile grid for a game, where the explosion propagates at most `strength` tiles in the cardinal directions, until it hits something in each direction (as detected by `explode()` returning false).

Comment: @hoapham Yes, but the problem is that if any of the statements is ```true```, then it will terminate the loop.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek agreed, but it is a guess. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common pattern when writing code for a tile grid. To efficiently handle it, you can write:

```java
public static final int[][] DIRECTIONS = {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}};

void explodeDirections(int x, int y, int strength) {
    for (int[] dir : DIRECTIONS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++) {
            if (!explode(x + (i * dir[0]), y + (i * dir[1]))) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

boolean explode(int x, int y) { /* some stuff */ }
```

But of course, this sort of idea can be implemented in any language (we've turned your manually-unrolled four individual loops into a single, outer loop). Note that the `break` will only stop execution of the inner loop, so this is functionally equivalent to your original code.

If a wrapper class `Vec2` was being used to contain `(x, y)` pairs together, you could define `DIRECTIONS` in a way which was not prone to array-out of bounds problems if the definition of `DIRECTIONS` was accidentally changed (since this would be enforced by the compiler at compilation time).

It is also easy to modify this to check diagonal directions as well (just add the pairs `{1, 1}`, `{-1, 1}`, `{1, -1}`, and `{-1, -1}` to `DIRECTIONS`).

Answer (score 2):

The original code looks fine to me.  It's clear as to what it means.  Not at all smelly.

Maybe I'd use a single loop termination condition instead of two; something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strength && !explode(x+i, y); i++)  {  
}
```

since I prefer to avoid jumps out of loops in simple situations.

But the existence of 4 loops to do 4 slightly-different things seems uncontroversial to me - probably clearer than the alternatives.

Comment: you have to remove the `!` before `explode` to make it functional equivalent

Answer (score 0):

If order of direction-check doesn't matter.

```
    void explodeDirections() {

        for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++) {
            if (!explode(x + i, y))
                break;
            if (!explode(x, y + i))
                break;
            if (!explode(x-i, y))
                break;
            if (!explode(x, y-i))
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not functionally equivalent to the code given in the question. Here any `break` will terminate the loop, but the original code will only `break` each individual loop checking in a particular direction.